# Can I use number as property name in Jackson mapper?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Spring MVC3.2 and Jackson for JSON mapping. I want to serialize and deserialize property name with just number. Here is my class:

```
public Usage implement Serializable {

  private String imei;

  @JsonIgnore
  @JsonProperty("4")
  private long j2j;

  @JsonIgnore
  @JsonProperty("8")
  private long call;


  //Getters and setters
}
```

JSON:

```
{"imei":"352985052917115", "4":20, "8":10}
```

Controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/alert")
public JsonResult<Void> handleOverUsageAlertByDevice(@RequestBody Usage usage){
    //Do something
}
```

But when I send the JSON to the controller, 404 Bad request error happens, saying:

```
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

Can I use number as Json property name?

Your answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Your JSON looks valid, according to the [json validator](http://jsonlint.com/), I'd look for the problem eleswhere in your code.

Comment: Try to send JSON with default property names. If everything will be OK, this is not a problem with numbers as property names. I think, we can use numbers as property names.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "numeric Strings" are perfectly legal JSON names, and Jackson supports them.
So problem should not be with that but something else in request handling.

Answer (score 0):

Please try by setting the content type when sending the request.
The content type should be set as "application/json".

Comment: This should be a comment.